# Клик на Последней 7 дней месяца .

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        },
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    });
    
 
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<p style="margin-left:10px;"><input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 1:30 PM - 01/01/2015 2:00 PM" /></p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
force some scrolling
```

Вопрос такой никак не могу решить чтобы при клике на  второй месяц (месяц который всегда справа) то есть на последнее 7 дней   второго месяца автоматический перешел на другой месяц.Если февраль  28 дней то при клике на 21,22,23,24,25,26,27 также на 28 должен перейти на март.Так как будто кто та кликнул на стрелочку наверху.Используется библиотека [`daterangepicker`](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) так же в нем использется `moment.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем? В каждом месяце есть одна неделя со следующего месяца. Эта неделя отображается серым. Если кликнуть по этой неделе, то происходит переход на следующий месяц. А если пользователь кликает в конкретный день текущего месяца, то он хочет выбрать именно этот день и никакой прокрутки не нужно

Более того, [документация](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) говорит, что в объекте возникают такие события

- `show.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the picker is shown
- `hide.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the picker is hidden
- `showCalendar.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the calendar(s) are shown
- `hideCalendar.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the calendar(s) are hidden
- `apply.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the apply button is clicked, or when a predefined range is clicked
- `cancel.daterangepicker`: Triggered when the cancel button is clicked

Как Вы видите, события клика на определенный день нет в принципе

Comment: а никак нельзя это реализовать ? :( @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: @Избытоксусликов С этим компонентом нет. Вы же видите, что нет способа отловить клик по дню. Можно, конечно, сделать реверс-енжинеринг, и добраться до самих дней через селекторы и навесить на них свой `onclick`, но к следующей версии селекторы могут измениться. Еще можно отредактировать исходники библиотеки и добавить нужное событие, или третий вариант - поискать другую библиотеку

Comment: При много благодарен